# Problem with git after cloning a folder in git

Tags: git, github

[image: issue]

I am facing this issue since I have cloned my repository and whenever a open a folder from my desktop and open the folder in vs code it shows these folders without even adding them or not even initi the git in my terminal.

Comment: It is telling you that some commited files were deleted in your working copy.

Comment: what does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` give? you seem to be inside a git repo, but not in the root directory.

Comment: please share text as copy/pasted text, not screenshots